# overflow-x: hidden, is not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, overflow

I have a site that works well on every browser, except on Safari. On safari I can scroll horizontally for many thousands of pixels.

Anyone have had this issue?

Comment: please provide a working example/code, codepen or link to your issue. overflow-x: hidden; works quite well in all browsers :) its some other issue.

Comment: The site link is www.kvf.fo/vix

Comment: you're trying to center your body tag. `body` tag is a special tag which in general shouldn't be styled much. Best practice is to wrap all your content inside another tag. e.g. instead of `<body>..code..</body>` do `<body><div class="wrap">..code..</div></body>` and try again. put `overflow-x:hidden` to body only.

Comment: This article solved my problem: https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/  - I switched from negative margin to box shadow. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On your site, you haven't declared `overflow-x: hidden` for your `html` tag. Adding it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes that solves the problem....but it cuts off the background color of the menu :/ Any workaround?

Comment: This article solved my problem: https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/  - I switched from negative margin to box shadow. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 13):

Tried the answer supplied above but it didn't fix my issue so I'm leaving my research / fix here for any others looking for help in the future.

I read that apparently Safari overlooks overflow when rendering so you have to target the body better? I gave the body a class and input the code below and this has fixed my issue.

```css
html, body {
 position:relative;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

OR

```css
html, .custom-body-class {
 position:relative;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: For some reason, I feel that making "html" and "body" relative is not a good idea ..

Comment: This creates double scroll for me - wierd behaviour. Safari, macOS.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit old but I recently stumbled on this problem and the selected answer did not work for me. jakelovelocks answer also gave me some bugs when setting position relative to the body. So my solution was to create a wrapper around the page and then add:

```
position:relative;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

to that wrapper instead of the body. It now works great without any problems.