# Horizontal Scroll only on Safari

Tags: html, css

I have an h-scroll that only happens on Safari (MAC).

For this site:

https://rapillolaw.com

What's strange is that for the body tag I put overflow-x: hidden, but that doesn't work.

Any advice? Again, I only see this on MAC Safari.

CSS:

```
body {
   color: #333;
   font: 20px "Lato", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;
   line-height: 1.75;
   height: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think its duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666663/overflow-x-hidden-is-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Hi, the proposed solution, adding "x-overflow:hidden" to the html tag messes up the scrolling on mobile. Not sure why, but it does. Thanks.