# Overflow-x not respected in Safari

Tags: css

I have implemented a mobile slide in menu using CSS and `overflow-x: hidden;` to hide the menu when translated off-screen. This rule is not respected on Safari on both Mac and iOS, but works perfectly well on Chrome and Firefox on Mac.

I’m not sure if it’s a bug in Safari or a problem with my CSS ruleset. Any input would be appreciated!

Here is my site: https://Finn.lesueur.nz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overflow-x: hidden, is not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666663/overflow-x-hidden-is-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: Yes, I had to add `position: relative;` to my html and body tags. I could have sworn I've never needed to do that before!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed to change the rule to:

```css
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666663/overflow-x-hidden-is-not-working-in-safari) linked by [moanth maji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4673371/moath-naji). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Mac and Safari but in `overflow-y` orientation. Only thing that I found that worked on a Mac that had 'hidden content' spilling over was

```
#elem {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: -webkit-paged-y;
    height: 200px;
    }
```

No other platform (including iPhone or iPad) required the `overflow-y: -webkit-paged-y;` plus a fixed height.